# MySql: How to update a single row occurrence from a table that has rows with duplicate fields?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table of (700+ rows) with the following format:

```
id | session | win
------------------
 1     1122     1
 2     1122     1
 3     1122     1
 4     4559     1
 5     4559     1
 6     4559     1
 7     4559     1
 8     4559     1
```

Where `win` is either `1` or `0`.
And `session` is not unique.

I want to update the group of rows that have the same `session`, and have all their `win` field set to `0` except for 1.

Goal:

```
id | session | win
------------------
 1     1122     1
 2     1122     0
 3     1122     0
 4     4559     1
 5     4559     0
 6     4559     0
 7     4559     0
 8     4559     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into consideration MySQL's horrible syntax to perform updates, the only way I can think of doing this is:

```
update t set win = 0
where id not in (
    select id from (
        select min(id) id from t
        group by session
    ) s
);
```

It'd also possible to join instead of group by but I think a group by in this case would be faster.

Answer (score 5):

Couple approaches set them all to 0 then update the min of each session to 1.

```
Update table set win = 0
update table set win = 1 where ID in (Select min(ID) from table group by session)
```

OR 
All in one

```
Update table set win=0 where ID not in (Select MIN(ID) from table group by session)
```

Comment: The first version is better. Nice answer.

Comment: Second one doesn't scale as well that's for sure. but with only 700+ records I din't think it would really matter.  anything below 40-50k performance difference between the two is negligible.

Comment: I'm getting an error for both queries: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'data' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Here is the query I used: Update `data` set win=0 where `id` not in (Select MIN(`id`) from `data` group by `session`)

Comment: Session might be a reserved word, as could data.  checking... If it's not too late rename data & session. Otherwise you'll need to escape them using ` I believe.